# Elasticsearch Arrays are not supported in superset (SQL API)

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, apache-superset

When I try to run the Query in superset which contain elastic search Array values I am getting following error -

```
elasticsearch error: TransportError(500, 'ql_illegal_argument_exception', 'Arrays (returned by [decision.certification.comments.user.sn]) are not supported')
```

My Query is : `SELECT "column_1" from "table_1";`

where  `column_1` contains the Array Values and I am trying to get those values into the table form in superset but Array Values are not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/preset-io/elasticsearch-dbapi#known-limitations) of the Superset `elasticsearch-dbapi` driver. ElasticSearch documentation for their own [SQL API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-limitations.html#_array_type_of_fields) explains the reason for this:

> Array fields are not supported due to the "invisible" way in which
> Elasticsearch handles an array of values: the mapping doesn’t indicate
> whether a field is an array (has multiple values) or not, so without
> reading all the data, Elasticsearch SQL cannot know whether a field is
> a single or multi value.